# Load all image from a folder on the website before opening it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created this simple HTML website where while scrolling background images are changed with jQuery. There are 500 images so while scrolling its like a silent film, it's really cool. My problem is images take time to load, so while scrolling most of them are just white, waiting to be loaded.
Can i somehow load them all before opening the website and allowing the user to scroll?

Comment: You could use the `onload()` event on images to not allow scrolling before all are done or put all as base64 in a css file. Yet with preloading the initial loading will take longer.

Comment: Before opening the website will be difficult, since we can't predict the future yet. ;) But once the website gets opened, you can preload all the images and give them long cache times. Have a look at `<link rel="preload">` in the docs.

Comment: You could assign an `eventListener` (`$(document).ready(function() {})` in jQuery) to your document that checks if the DOM is loaded. If it has finished loading, allow to scroll.